# Strongloop on Openshift - what datasources entries do I have to make for a mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, openshift, strongloop, mysql-connector

I've created an Openshift App with the StrongLoop Suite Cartridge. There seems to be an problem with the mysql-Connection. If I use the in-memory-db it's working. Nonetheless, this is my datasources.json:

```
{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "mysql",
        "host": "<name>.rhcloud.com",
        "port": 3306,
        "database": "myapi",
        "username": "<mysql_username>",
        "password": "<mysql_pwd>"
    }
}
```

I have also tried putting my Mysql-IP (127.5.223.2) in the "host"-field above. Same error.

My logfile looks like this:

```
==> strongloop/logs/node.log <==
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/var/lib/openshift/5742da752d527124130000a6/strongloop//bin/node/node" "/var/lib/openshift/5742da752d527124130000a6/strongloop/bin/node/npm" "start" "-d"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/5742da752d527124130000a6/app-root/runtime/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/5742da752d527124130000a6/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Do I have to somehow pass the SSH credentials somewhere?
Is there anybody who is able to help me?

Comment: Is `loopback-connector-mysql` included as a dependency in `package,json`?

Comment: @JiriFiala No I hadn't. I've added it now ("loopback-connector-mysql": "^1.4.7") but it's still not working.
What host adress do I have to write in the config.json file? Is it "0.0.0.0"? And in the same file, which port do I have to specify?

Comment: you should use [OpenShift MySQL environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mysql.html) $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT to read the host address and port. Examples of reading environment variables can be found [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#reading-variable-examples).